# Code coverage tool for linux drivers

Tags: linux, code-coverage, linux-device-driver

I am looking for code coverage tool which can give functional and conditional coverage for linux drivers.

The tool should generate html output. I was using bullseye till now for C++ apps. But i am not able to find anything for linux kernel modules.

Answer (score 1):

Using our [source-code instrumentation technology for test coverage and profiling](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Company/Publications/TestCoverage.pdf), we profiled the Linux kernel some ten years back using our
[C profiler](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/CProfiler.html) tool.   A corresponding [C Test Coverage](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/CTestCoverage.html) exists.

Such instrumentation gives you very low overhead instrumentation, suitable for drivers,  rather complete control of what is instrumented (OK, do the drivers instead of the kernel) and control of how and when to collect the test coverage data (collect in a kernel buffer and access through a dummy driver).

The exported coverage data can be superimposed on the source code to give the programmer a direct view of what is covered, or can be exported as an XML file, to be easily reformatted into HTML.